# Padding a numpy array with zeros, and using another array as an index for ones

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

I'm trying to pad a `numpy` array, and I cannot seem to find the right approach from the documentation for numpy. I have an array:

```
a = array([2, 1, 3, 5, 7])
```

This represents the index for an array I wish to create. So at index value 2 or 1 or 3 etc I would like to have a one in the array, and everywhere else in the target array, to be padded with zeros. Sort of like an array mask. I would also like to specify the overall length of the target array, `l`. So my ideal function would like something like:

```
>>> foo(a,l)
array([0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
```

, where `l=10` for the above example.

EDIT:

So I wrote this function:

```
def padwithones(a,l) :
    p = np.zeros(l)
    for i in a :
        p = np.insert(p,i,1)
    return p
```

Which gives:

```
Out[19]: 
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.])
```

Which isn't correct!

Comment: have you tried anything? Maybe using `np.zeros` and then indexed assignment...??

Comment: so use a generator maybe to determine when a one is to inserted into the `np.zeros` array?

Comment: No. just `array_of_zeroes[a] = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is basically a one-hot array:

```
def onehot(foo, l):
    a = np.zeros(l, dtype=np.int32)
    a[foo] = 1
    return a
```

Example:

```
In [126]: onehot([2, 1, 3, 5, 7], 10)
Out[126]: array([0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0])
```

Comment: that's great. Thanks!

Comment: If you use`dtype=bool` it would take 1/4th the space.